# Set language in Power BI Embedded

Tags: iframe, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are using Power BI Embedded to show statistics. Power BI embedded works by iframes. We have users from many different countries and their browser language setting affects the iframed report to create a mix of languages where the table names are in english (hard coded in the report) but some other texts are translated to the users language. For instance it says "Searches av Date" instead of "Searches by Date".

Is there any way to set the language of the iframe to english?

I know that an alternative is to create separate report files for each language thus creating a fully translated experience but that would require us to manage 20 different pbix files and that is not manageable.

[image: Searches av Date]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table, which contains all titles and the language identifier, then you can use a card instead of the title and add the right value to the card with a filter. The filter must be set to the language you want. You can use the javascript api, to set filters.